# How to connect a SAS expander like RES2SV240?

Tags: sas

I'm afraid this is going to be a very noob question, sorry.

I am looking at the [RES2SV240](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/servers/raid/raid-controller-res2sv240.html) card from Intel. I have never used SAS or an expander, and I'm a bit confused about how it works.

First, the description on their website says the card has 8 SFF-8087 connectors. The picture next to it only shows 6 connectors. Is that a mistake in the description?

Second, and really my main question, how does one connect this up? From other discussions I've read, the PCIe connector is only for power. So if I connect the 6 connectors to 24 HDDs, how do I connect the RAID/JBOD controller? Or do I have to keep at least one SFF-8087 to connect to the controller and therefore be limited to 20 HDDs?

Comment: I'm on an anti-Intel kick of late as their products have been causing another SF user headaches. Make sure you read Ed's answer in the Dupe question and get a feel for what the DIY community before jumping in.

Comment: It certainly does seem to be a typo on their website. There is clearly only 6 ports, and 6x4 = 24 so that all adds up.

Answer (score 1):

The [product brief](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/servers/raid-expander-res2sv240-brief.html) is explicit on the number of connectors:

> Six SFF8087 SAS/SATA connectors for attaching up to 24 targets or initiators

And yes, you would need to "sacrifice" at least one port for controller connection.